# QGIS Least Cost Path Analysis taking forever

Tags: qgis, mapping, slope, cost-path, least-cost

I have been trying to calculate the Least Cost Path (LCP) between two points on my map. These points are approximately 100km apart. I have created a slope from my DEM raster, created proper vector points and files for the two points. The LCP function will run without any errors, however, it is taking foreverrrr. It took 130 minutes to complete just 16% of the analysis, so I gave up.

Is there any way to speed up this process? Is my map too big?

I have tried a few suggested ways to optimize QGIS. I also tried to clear my computer cache in hopes of allocating more power to QGIS. My computer is used for research analysis so it is not low-preformance.